# How long can it take to generate a $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: descriptive-set-theory, set-theory

I want to know if there is a $\sigma$-algebra such that for every countable ordinal $\alpha$ the $\sigma$-algebra can be generated in more than $\alpha$ steps but less than $\omega_{1}$ steps.

Given an algebra of sets $(X,\mathcal{A})$, let $\mathcal{A}_{0}=\mathcal{A}$, and for all ordinals $0<\alpha\leq\omega_{1}$, let $\mathcal{A}_{\alpha}$ be the algebra of sets generated by countable unions from the collection $\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}\mathcal{A}_{\beta}$. Clearly $\mathcal{A}_{\omega_{1}}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$.

1. For each countable ordinal $\alpha$ does there exist an algebra of sets $(X,\mathcal{A})$ such that $\mathcal{A}_{\alpha}\neq\mathcal{A}_{\omega_{1}}$, but where $\mathcal{A}_{\beta}=\mathcal{A}_{\omega_{1}}$ for some countable ordinal $\beta$?
2. Does there exist a $\sigma$-algebra $(X,\mathcal{M})$ such that

   1. If $(X,\mathcal{A})$ is an algebra of sets that generates $\mathcal{M}$, then 
      $\mathcal{A}_{\alpha}=\mathcal{M}$ for some countable ordinal $\alpha$, and
   2. for each countable ordinal $\alpha$ there is an algebra of sets $(X,\mathcal{A})$ that generates $\mathcal{M}$ but where $\mathcal{A}_{\alpha}\neq\mathcal{M}$?

Comment: Countable unions are not enough.  You will also need either complements or countable intersections.

Comment: Gerald, he said "the algebra...generated by countable unions", which would provide the complements.

Comment: +1. I like this question very much!

Comment: I have taken a small liberty of using nested lists and improve the second question. I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer to the first question is in the positive; thanks to a corollary drawn by Ken Kunen from a key theorem (about Boolean algebras) of Arnie Miller. More specifically, as shown in Theorem 9.2 of [Arnie Miller's beautiful monograph](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.lnl/1235423343), we have the following:

> **Theorem** (Miller-Kunen) For every countable ordinal $\alpha$ there is a field $H$ of sets such that $o(H)=\alpha$.

In the above, $H$ is a field of sets means that $H$ is a family of subsets of some set $X$, and $H$ is closed under complements and finite unions; and $o(H)$ measures the length of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $H$ [see p.10 of the aforementioned reference for the official definition].

Comment: Do you mean Theorem 9.2 here: http://www.math.wisc.edu/~miller/res/dstfor.pdf ? Well, it does not say anything about $\sigma$-completeness.

Comment: @Tomek: thanks, you are right. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Wait, what is the issue? It seems that Miller's definitions match the OP's, modulo the synonyms 'field of sets' and 'algebra of sets'.

Comment: @François: there is only issue of clarity, not veracity; the current edit addresses that.

Comment: OK, I see. (I fixed the link to Miller's book which got mangled after the edit.)

Comment: Ali Enayat. Thanks for the answer. And Miller's book looks interesting, so I will want to look through it some time. 